# Instaloader download_profiles with post_filter example?

Tags: instaloader

I'm trying to download a profile with posts after a certain date as a test.  I have the simple code:

```
L = instaloader.Instaloader(save_metadata=False, download_comments=False)
L.download_profiles(Profiles, posts=True, fast_update=True, post_filter="date_utc >= datetime(2019, 1, 1)")
```

It works fine without the `post_filter`, but with the `post_filter`, I get:

```
<Post BOJaRXwhIix> skipped. Filter evaluation failed: 'str' object is not callable
<Post BOJZ6nqhpkX> skipped. Filter evaluation failed: 'str' object is not callable
<Post BHDC70ShoOs> skipped. Filter evaluation failed: 'str' object is not callable
```

I think I'm missing something obvious, but the documentation says that the `post_filter` string should be a Python-legal boolean statement, and I got this example directly from the [command-line filter example in the docs](https://instaloader.github.io/cli-options.html#cmdoption-post-filter).  Advice?

Answer (score 0):

```
L.download_profiles(Profiles, posts=True, fast_update=True, post_filter=lambda post: post.date_utc >= datetime(2019, 1, 1))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. In general, dumping code isn't nearly as helpful as an answer that includes code and an explanation.